# How do I get Graphics drivers / bluetooth / card reader working on an Acer Aspire V3-571G?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, bluetooth, hybrid-graphics

A couple of days ago I bought an Acer Aspire V3-571G laptop without a system installed on it. The only thing that was there was Linux Linpus. I created a bootable CD with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit - I read that my processor was 64 bit and that it might be a good configuration for my gear (I'm not especially fluent with all the computer stuff, still trying to learn) and replaced Linpus with Ubuntu.

Everything seemed to work fine, but there're few exceptions to that which came pass my way.

1. My bluetooth doesn't work. It seems to be switched on, but when I check my system settings the button is actually off, and I can't drag it 'perminently' to the 'on' position. Tried a couple of commands I found on the net, none of them helped and there was no word whatsoever  in my BIOS settings about enabling bluetooth.
2. My card reader has some serious problems with copying more than one file at a time. I tried to put some music on my phone through a MicroSD card adapter (because my bluetooth doesn't work) and it got stuck every single time I copied an album on it.
3. I'm not sure if all my drivers were properly installed, so I checked in the terminal if it could tell me sth about my graphics.

   typed: `sudo lshw -c display` and what i got was:

   ```
   *-display UNCLAIMED     
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: NVIDIA Corporation
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        version: a1
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
        configuration: latency=0
        resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128)
   *-display
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 2
        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
        version: 09
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
        resources: irq:44 memory:b3000000-b33fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
   ```

As I said I'm no expert and not english-speaking generally, but it doesn't seem to be right. I've got a *NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M*.

Comment: Did you look on the proprietary driver for the bluetooth driver?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to correct the **brightness adjustment** problem:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Then type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It will ask for your password. Type it in.
3. Around the 11th line, there will be something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save the file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
5. Reboot and see if backlight adjustment works. If not, undo the changes you did above, by invoking the text editor as in steps 1 and 2.

Hope it helps.

Works for Acer Aspire v3-571,Acer Aspire v3 571g,Hewlett Packard Bell EasyNote TS,Acer Aspire 4755G,Acer Aspire 5750-6866

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same laptop a while ago - unfortunately there are quite a few problems with the hardware under linux (for me - maybe you'll have better luck)

so here is what I can help with

1. For the Bluetooth, i think the problem is that you have it Hard blocked on your machine. Hitting Fn + F3 should toggle between all the variation of WiFi on/off, BT on/off. use the command
   `rfkill list`
   to see current state (you may need to wait a few seconds for the change)
   But for me this doesn't fix BT performance - it fails to list the available devices. I tried with a BT mouse and a phone ... there are some guides you can find on the net for this - none worked reliably for me.
2. haven't used this, so dunno
3. The issue is that the 640M uses the NVidia Optimus technology ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus ) which isn't officially supported on linux, but this howto shows how you can get it working:
   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Other issues i have include not being able to control the screen brightness (Fn + Left/Right arrow key) or even from the display settings.

And for the WiFi it seems i managed to have it work reliably by having BT hard blocked and creating the file
`/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`
with contents
`options ath9k nohwcrypt=1`
But this means no BT mouse.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 12.10 not 12.04 on a Aspire V3-571G and there is a package you can install and some commands to fix your bluetooth.

See: [Bug #1024884: Bluetooth with AR9462 WLAN/BT-Combo don't work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1024884)

Download `ar9462-dkms_1.4-3.5_all.deb`
and `linux-firmware_1.100_all.deb`

Instructions would be:

`` sudo apt-get install g++ dkms linux-headers-`uname -r` ``
`sudo dpkg -i Downloads/linux-firmware_1.100_all.deb`
`sudo dpkg -i Downloads/ar9462-dkms_1.4-3.5_all.deb`
`sudo dkms install ar9462/1.4-3.5`
`dkms status`

You should see:
`ar9462, 1.4-3.5, 3.5.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed`

Reboot and enjoy.

I'm using a bluetooth mouse now, but before the "hcitool scan" would return nothing.